# Why won't Mathematica display an answer?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have the following piece of code that relates 4 variables: a1, a2, b1, and b2. There are 4 independent equations (including a1=1), meaning that all variables should have a unique solution. But the result is just empty for b2. And if I try to solve for a2, it just displays the first line of the matrix equation that I put in. What is going on here?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a1 = 1;
Solve[{a2, b2} ==
   {{t, -I*κ}, {-I*κ, t}}.{a1, b1} && 
  b1 == b2*Exp[-I*(2 π)/λ*n*2 π*R], b2]
```

Comment: That is a weird way to specify a system of quations. Try `Solve[{a2, b2} == {{t, -I*\[Kappa]}, {-I*\[Kappa], t}}.{a1, b2*Exp[-I*(2 \[Pi])/\[Lambda]*n*2 \[Pi]*R]}, {a2, b2}]`

Comment: It actually makes a lot of sense to specify them separately in the context that I'm using them. If I could, I'd even put a1==1 inside Solve. I don't want to have to manually insert b1 into all the places it will appear. Imagine having 20 equations, what would I do then?

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it, maybe not the best way, is the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a1 = 1;
eqs = Thread[{a2, b2} == {{t, -I*κ}, {-I*κ, t}}.{a1, b1}]
AppendTo[eqs, b1 == b2*Exp[-I*(2 π)/λ*n*2 π*R]]
Solve[eqs, {a2, b1, b2}]// Flatten // Last
```

`Solve` does not seem to like it when the number of equations is not the same as the number of variables.  Sometimes I try to eliminate certain variables myself, like this:

```
Eliminate[eqs, {a2, b1}]
Solve[%, b2]
```

This is reasonable behavior for `Solve`.  After all, we have already told `Solve` that `b2 == b1 t - I κ`.  What more do we want?  We have to provide some guidance by specifying the other dependent variables or by eliminating them ourselves.

Although using `Eliminate` is effective, using `Exists` as suggested by @jjc385 may be more appealing, especially to us who want to extend our knowledge of Mathematica:

```
Solve[Exists[{a2, b1}, And @@ eqs], b2]
```

If we wish to treat `a1` as a parameter without assigning a value to it, we can do so like this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqs = Thread[{a2, b2} == {{t, -I*κ}, {-I*κ, t}}.{a1, b1}];
AppendTo[eqs, b1 == b2*Exp[-I*(2 π)/λ*n*2 π*R]];
Solve[Exists[{a2, b1}, And @@ eqs], b2]
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Can you add the possibility of doing `Solve[Exists[{a2,b1}, And@@eqs, b2]`?  Also, it might be good to mention the second "possible issue" in the docs for `Solve`, which mentions the issue.  +1

Comment: If one is not afraid of *undocumented* syntax: `Solve[eqs, b2, {a2, b1}]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use your approach if you ask [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for `{a2, b1, b2}`

```
a1 = 1;
soln1 = Solve[{a2, b2} == {{t, -I*κ}, {-I*κ, t}}.{a1, b1} && 
    b1 == b2*Exp[-I*(2 π)/λ*n*2 π*R], {a2, b1, b2}][[1]]

(*  {a2 -> (E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) t - t^2 - κ^2)/(
  E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t), 
 b1 -> -((I κ)/(E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t)), 
 b2 -> -((I E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) κ)/(
   E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t))}  *)
```

You can also include `a1==1` either directly,

```
Clear[a1]
soln2 = Solve[
   And @@ Thread[{a2, b2} == {{t, -I*κ}, {-I*κ, t}}.{a1, b1}] &&
     b1 == b2*Exp[-I*(2 π)/λ*n*2 π*R] && a1 == 1, {a2, b1, 
    b2}][[1]]

(*  {a2 -> (E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) t - t^2 - κ^2)/(
  E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t), 
 b1 -> -((I κ)/(E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t)), 
 b2 -> -((I E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) κ)/(
   E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t))}  *)
```

or as an assumption to [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) or [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
soln3 = Solve[
    And @@ Thread[{a2, b2} == {{t, -I*κ}, {-I*κ, t}}.{a1, b1}] &&
      b1 == b2*Exp[-I*(2 π)/λ*n*2 π*R], {a2, b1, b2}][[1]] // 
  Simplify[#, a1 == 1] &

(*  {a2 -> -((-E^(((4 I n π^2 R)/λ)) t + t^2 + κ^2)/(
   E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t)), 
 b1 -> -((I κ)/(E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t)), 
 b2 -> -((I E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) κ)/(
   E^((4 I n π^2 R)/λ) - t))}  *)
```

Verifying that all three approaches are equivalent

```
({a2, b1, b2} /. soln1) == ({a2, b1, b2} /. soln2) == ({a2, b1, b2} /. 
    soln3) // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```